# Typescript import for an npm package without a definition

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've got an npm package (@salesforce/canvas-js-sdk) which doesn't have a Typescript definition file for it. I'm using React and so I'm using the "import from" syntax to pull in depenencies. Visual Studio seems to dislike that there isn't a definition file for the module. Also, this module is supposed to expose a property on the "window" object called Sfdc. How can I define a definition file for this npm package without modifying the package?

---

What I've been attempting:

This is what my current import statements look like.

[image]

I then defined a very simple definition for the module like so.

[image]

That resolves the compilation errors where it couldn't find the module definition. But if I try to use the Sfdc object like in the example it doesn't work.

Here is a picture from the documenation for how to use the library with plain JavaScript. 
[image]

But that code doesn't work for me at runtime if I copy and paste it. Instead I can only get a reference to the Sfdc object if I use

[image]

### Solution

Because the package was built on a global object, I needed to simplify the import statement. I couldn't just exclude the import because the package code wouldn't be included on the page.
[image]

Then I had to change my d.ts file to declare the Sfdc object globally. 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that the module isn't actually a module (it's a global object exposed), you'll want your custom typings to match that.

Instead of `declare module '@salesforce/canvas-js-sdk'` try writing `declare namespace Sfdc`.

You should then be able to remove the import statements and access the global `Sfdc` variable directly from anywhere in your code.

Comment: As soon as I don't do "declare module '@salesforce/canvas-js-sdk'" then I get the error on the import statement. Could not find a declaration file for module '@salesforce/canvas-js-sdk'. 'C:/code/AzureServices/SFDCWebsite2/node_modules/@salesforce/canvas-js-sdk/js/canvas-all.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.

Comment: When declaring a namespace you no longer need to use import statments. Import statements are for when you need to import from a module. But the package is built as a global object, not a module, so import statements mean nothing. Just delete your import statments for the package.

Comment: Thanks, I did still have to import but this answer led me in the right direction. I posted more details on my solution at the bottom of the question.